# How do I modify and include updatePerson() function in my current code?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, crud

This is my collection in Firebase Firestore:

`final CollectionReference _persons = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Persons');`

This is my current code:

```
Future<String> uploadImage(File imageFile) async {
    String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    Reference reference =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('images/$fileName');
    UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(imageFile);
    TaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot =
        await uploadTask.whenComplete(() => null);
    String downloadUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    return downloadUrl;
  }

  Future<void> addPerson(BuildContext context) async {
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    String? _name;
    String? _gender;
    DateTime? _birthdate;
    File? _image;

    void _selectImage() async {
      final pickedFile =
          await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
      setState(() {
        _image = File(pickedFile!.path);
      });
    }

    await showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 40),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 20,
                    left: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom + 20
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        _selectImage();
                      },
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 50,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
                        backgroundImage:
                            _image != null ? FileImage(_image!) : null,
                        child: _image == null
                            ? Icon(
                                Icons.add_a_photo,
                                size: 50,
                                color: Colors.grey[800],
                              )
                            : null,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter a name';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _name = value;
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Gender'),
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'Please enter a gender';
                        }
                        return null;
                      },
                      onSaved: (value) {
                        _gender = value;
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
                            context: context,
                            initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                            firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                            lastDate: DateTime.now());
                        if (picked != null) {
                          setState(() {
                            _birthdate = picked;
                          });
                        }
                      },
                      child: IgnorePointer(
                        child: TextFormField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Birthdate'),
                          controller: TextEditingController(
                              text: _birthdate != null
                                  ? DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(_birthdate!)
                                  : ''),
                          validator: (value) {
                            if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                              return 'Please select a birthdate';
                            }
                            return null;
                          },
                          onSaved: (value) {},
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          _formKey.currentState!.save();
                          final String? imageUrl =
                              _image != null ? await uploadImage(_image!) : null;
                          await _persons.add({
                            'name': _name,
                            'gender': _gender,
                            'birthdate': _birthdate,
                            'avatar': imageUrl
                          });
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text('Add Person'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

And this is the updatePerson function that I would like to combine with my above code:

```
Future<void> updatePerson(String personId, String name, String gender, DateTime birthdate, File? imageFile) async {
  // Update the fields in the document with the given data
  Map<String, dynamic> data = {
    'name': name,
    'gender': gender,
    'birthdate': Timestamp.fromDate(birthdate)
  };

  if (imageFile != null) {
    // Upload the new image to Firebase Storage and update the 'avatar' field with its download URL
    String imageUrl = await uploadImage(imageFile);
    data['avatar'] = imageUrl;
  }

  // Update the document in the 'Persons' collection with the new data
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Persons').doc(personId).update(data);
}
```

I tried combining, but I am having difficulty since I am still new to using Firebase Firestore with Flutter. The reason why I want to combine the updatePerson function with the addPerson function is to lessen the code in my project. I need help; frustrated by reading many internet blogs, and youtube somehow is not helping.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to achieve? Update does something different than create a new person.

Comment: I want to update an existing Person if it is already present in the Firebase Firestore, my document fields are name,gender,birthdate,avatar. @tomerpacific